# Did Google places API have information about nearby Restaurant menus?

Tags: android, google-places-api

I actually want to make an app like FoodPanda. I have searched a lot about how Foodpanda is gettinng menu of different restaurants but did't find anything helpful. Now my question is "did google places API provide restaurants menu or FoodPanda have their own database?"

any help will be appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Places API does not provide menu information.

E.g. the [Place details documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResults) for the Google Places API Web Service shows an `opening_hours` and `reviews` fields, but nothing about menus.